# c++ getter not returning value (NULL)

Tags: c++, return, console-application, return-value, getter

when i try to `cout` the get function it don't return any value !

my header file :

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Dog
{
private:
    string dogName = "Max";
public:
    Dog();
    void talking();
    void jumping();
    void setDogName(string newDogName);
    ///////thats the function /////
    string getDogName();
};
```

my cpp file :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Dog.h"
using namespace std;


Dog::Dog() {
    cout << " Dog has been Created " << endl;

}
void Dog::setDogName(string newDogName)
{
    newDogName = dogName;
}
string Dog::getDogName()
{
    return dogName;
}
```

and my main.cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

#include "Dog.h"
#include "Cat.h"

int main()
{
    Dog ewila;

    ewila.setDogName("3wila");

    cout << ewila.getDogName();


    return 0;
}
```

im learning c++ new so i don't know whats happening even i tried to type `ewila.getDogName();` by itself and it didn't do anything 
and i tried to store the `setDogname()` in a variable to return with the `getDogName()` and also nothing i don't know what i'm doing wrong 
**also :** **im using *visual studio 2017* and i run the program from** ***visual c++ 2015 MSBuild command prompt***

Comment: In your  ``setDogName`` method do this: ``dogName = newDogName;``

Comment: If you would have passed the string by `const string&`, you would have seen your error in the `setDogName` function since the compiler would not have allowed assigning to `newDogName`.  In other words `void Dog::setDogName(const string& newDogName)`.

Comment: oh man ! thank you so much !!!! i tried everything but not that ! i'm so noob !! thank you

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in line `newDogName = dogName;` of function `void Dog::setDogName(string newDogName)`. You are using `assignment operator`(`=`) incorrectly. This should be `dogName =newDogName;`

So the corrected CPP file will be:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Dog.h"
using namespace std;


Dog::Dog() {
    cout << " Dog has been Created " << endl;
}
void Dog::setDogName(string newDogName)
{
    dogName = newDogName;
}
string Dog::getDogName()
{
    return dogName;
}
```